# A regular regularity lemma

Tags: graph-theory

Does anyone know of a result along the lines of

-The reduced graph of a Szemeredi partition of a regular graph is approximately regular?

I am using the degree form of the Regularity lemma. Here my graph $G$ on $n$ vertices is such that all vertices have degree (1/2 + $\epsilon$)$n$ and I want that the reduced graph (where the vertices are the clusters from the Szemeredi partition, and we have edges if we have epsilon regularity of positive degree between clusters between clusters) almost inherits this regularity condition with some different epsilon. Has anyone used this before?